Windows 7 и браузеры
Есть ноут Lenovo на Windows 7 SP3. В целом он отлично работает:
немного тормозит (но пашет!) PyCharm,
прекрасно работает Wolfram Mathematica 12
и т.д.
Но с браузерами беда. Перечитал массу советов, как настроить Firefox или Chrome,
как еще браузеры быстро работают с Win 7 - ничего не помогает, даже почта еле грузится.
Это очень странно, неужели скрипты загрузки почты сложнее PyCharm?!
Может все же есть возможность настроить минималки для браузеров для Windows 7?

Поставьте себе ubuntu

Посмотрите: https://github.com/minbrowser/min

с браузерами беда, потому что ваш ноут - ничего не может, процессор скорее всего никакущщий, быстрой памяти нет, диск - плох; а все современные браузеры крайне многопоточны [точнее - работают как куча процессов], и требовательны к скорости памяти и диска; т.е. по сути пользовать современный браузер без 4-ядерного процессора, без быстрой памяти и диска - бессмыслица; убунту здесь не поможет, браузеры и на какой то убунте будут хотеть 4 ядра и быструю память

Стационар Win7, CPU: DualCore_x2_2.5GHz, DDR2=2Gb, SATA=250Gb, Chrome_v109 -- всё работает без ощутимых тормозов.

@PRODIGY, а существует экспорт настроек в Chrome? Ну как-то, чтобы ваши данные не попали.
Если сможете такое сделать, скиньте пожалуйста куда-нибудь!

@InterceptorTSK, Wolfram Mathematica и тем более PyCharm тоже весьма требовательны.
Есть и 4 ядра, и памяти хватает. Что-то не так с браузерами, ну так есть же настройки.
Уверен, можно что-то сделать.

"Есть и 4 ядра, и памяти хватает" - это не ядра, а агрызки; в ноутах по определению не может стоять полноценных ядер, частоты задушены, кешей нет, память задушена и так далее; чудес нет и не бывает, если в ноут поставить железки от обычного компа - ноут банально поплывёт от перегрева; рассмотрите возможность хотя бы поверхностной диагностики вашего ноута, что-то совсем душит ваш ноут так, что на браузеры ресурсов не остаётся
